# how to pass value to prop of type PropTypes.node.isRequired to jest enzyme test?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

i am writing jest test for react component using enzyme.I have to pass value to props for snapshot testing. How to pass value to prop types:

```
  Foo.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
text: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }
```

Foo.test.jsx:

```
it('captures screenshot of foo', ()=> {
const renderedvalue = renderer.create(<Foo text='test' />.toJSOn();
expect(renderedvalue).toMatchSnapshot();
{);
```

As children isrequired , so it gives warning to pass value for it. But i am not sure how to pass value for it. I tried :

```
const children= <div />
const renderedvalue = renderer.create(<Foo text='test'  children={children}/>.toJSOn();
```

But it failed. Similarly, there is another property PropTypes.object.isrequired

card: PropTypes.object.isRequired

Can someone please help me in knowing how to pass values for these 2 prop types to enzyme snapshot testing.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

`children` is a special prop that is built in.  It means that the component wraps other components or elements.

Try like this:

```
it('captures screenshot of foo', ()=> {
const renderedvalue = renderer.create(
    <Foo text='test'>
        </div>hello</div>
    </Foo>
    ).toJSOn();
expect(renderedvalue).toMatchSnapshot();
{);
```

Comment: i tried this way but i am getting following error: Invariant Violation: getNodeFromInstance: Invalid argument                                                              renderer.create(<Foo> <div> hello</div> </Foo>).toJSON();